# Generating a 'random style' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that would return a new text style (`none`, `bold`, `italic` or `bold` and `italic`).
Here is my code:

```
function generateRandomStyle(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    switch(random){
        case 0:
            return;
            break;
        case 1:
            var i = document.createElement("i");
            return i;
            break;
        case 2:
            var b = document.createElement("b");
            return b;
            break;
        case 3:
            var b=document.createElement("b");
            var i = document.createElement("i");
            b.appendChild(i);
            return b;
            break;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I assign this function to a variable (e.g var `_style = generateRandomStyle();` )

I sometimes get this error:

> TypeError: _style is undefined.

How can I fix that? I suppose it comes from the last case of the switch statement.

Comment: You get the error at the assignment statement, or when you try and use the value?

Comment: Note that case 0 doesn't return anything.

Comment: 1. You don't need to break after a return. Think about what gets returned when `random` == 0.

Comment: I get the error when I try to use the value.

Comment: It comes from the first case of the switch, where you return nothing

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, the `random` will return 0 at some point which doesn't have any outcome handled in the `switch`. If you set it to `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;` the issue is resolved. Either that, or add some handling for the `case 0:`

Also, you can safely take out the `break` statements are they are unreachable.

```js
function generateRandomStyle(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    console.log(random)
    switch(random){
        case 0:
            return;
        case 1:
            var i = document.createElement("i");
            return i;

        case 2:
            var b = document.createElement("b");
            return b;
        case 3:
            var b=document.createElement("b");
            var i = document.createElement("i");
            b.appendChild(i);
            return b;
    }
}

console.log(generateRandomStyle())
```

Version with allowed return of 'undefined'

```js
function generateRandomStyle(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    console.log(random)
    switch(random){
        case 0:
            return;
        case 1:
            var i = document.createElement("i");
            return i;
        case 2:
            var b = document.createElement("b");
            return b;
        case 3:
            var b=document.createElement("b");
            var i = document.createElement("i");
            b.appendChild(i);
            return b;
    }
}

var style = generateRandomStyle()
console.log(style === undefined ? 'none' : style)
```

Comment: Indeed, that seems to fix my problem. However, my function never generates a '<b><i>'

Comment: That is a weird one, notice the `<b>` returned for `case 3`: in the example seems to return a nested element?

Comment: Yes, furthermore, it never generates a 'non-style'.

Comment: In your original code, you process 0 but don't return anything. You'd need to return something to allow you to have no style, or handle the `undefined`. You may want to simply return some other indicator to allow you to intercept this before applying the styling. Added above, you can then use this variable to do as you wish e.g. only process the style when it's not `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

G0dsquad already pointet out the issue with the 0-based value.

Another issue you have to solve, is that you actually never hit the max value by `floor` and `random`. This is defined by their specification:

### random

Random will never return the max value.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
>   The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range.

### floor

Floor will never return a value greater than the input.

```
Math.floor( 2.95); //  2
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor
>   The Math.floor() function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
```

Comment: This is hardly an answer. You need to explain why this code solves the problem, and how it differs from the OP's code.